# Dismiss MacOS Big Sur notifications with keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, macos-big-sur

I have long used an Applescript triggered from a keyboard shortcut to dismiss notifications on MacOS. It worked by simulating a click of the "close" button of every open Notification Center window.

Since upgrading to Big Sur (currently 11.0.1), notifications no longer have a close button. Instead, when you hover over them with the mouse, an "X" button will appear. For a person who has difficulty clicking precisely (I have a slight hand tremor), using the mouse/trackpad is difficult.

Anyone have suggestions on how to restore that functionality so I can just keep my hands on the keyboard?

Comment: Looks like this is answered here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408019/dismiss-macos-big-sur-notifications-with-keyboard#:~:text=Since%20upgrading%20to%20Big%20Sur,%22X%22%20button%20will%20appear.

Answer (score 0):

Found this https://itectec.com/askdifferent/macos-dismiss-macos-big-sur-notifications-with-keyboard/.
I tested it worked.  The minor error is process name is 'NotificationCenter' without space. Original code may cause process not found error.
Credit belongs to the original author from the link.

```
activate application "NotificationCenter"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NotificationCenter"
        set theWindow to group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Notification Center"
        # click theWindow
        set theActions to actions of theWindow
        repeat with theAction in theActions
            if description of theAction is "Close" then
                tell theWindow
                    perform theAction
                end tell
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```